# Tangents to the parabola

Tags: conic-sections

Quite a straightforward piece of maths I can't seem to get my head around here:

> The tangent to the parabola at the point $(4a, 4a)$ is given by what equation?

Bearing in mind the parabola is $y^2 = 4ax$ and the general point $(at^2, 2at)$ lies on the parabola.

Comment: Do you know about implicit differentiation? You need to find the derivative first

Comment: @SamWeatherhog forgive me but what do I differentiate?

Comment: @PontiusPilateVII You differentiate both sides of $y^2=4ax$ with respect to $x$. The left-hand side is done via the chain rule to get $2yy'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to compute the tangents to $y=\frac{1}{4a}x^2$ by differentiation? If we take the point $(t,\frac{1}{4a}t^2)$, the tangent has equation
$$
y-\frac{1}{4a}t^2=\frac{1}{2a}t(x-t)
$$
because the derivative of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{4a}x^2$ is $x\mapsto \frac{1}{2a}x$. For $t=4a$, we get
$$
y-\frac{1}{4a}16a^2=\frac{1}{2a}4a(x-4a)
$$
that is
$$
y-4a=2x-8a
$$
or
$$
y=2x-4a
$$

Just swap $x$ with $y$ and the requested tangent will be
$$
x=2y-4a
$$

Note that swapping $x$ with $y$ is an isometry, so it preserves tangents.

Let's make another example. Suppose you want to compute the normal to the parabola at the point $(a,-2a)$. You can do it in a very similar way, by computing the normal to the parabola $y=\frac{1}{4a}x^2$ at the point $(-2a,a)$. The tangent will be
$$
y-a=\frac{1}{2a}\cdot(-2a)(x+2a)
$$
or
$$
y-a=-x-2a
$$
that is
$$
y=-x-a
$$
The normal is thus
$$
y=x-a
$$
so the required normal is
$$
x=y-a
$$
(by swapping back $x$ with $y$).

Comment: @PontiusPilateVII If you swap $x$ with $y$ in your given equation, you get $x^2=4ay$, that is, $y=\dfrac{1}{4a}x^2$.

Comment: @PontiusPilateVII Where's the difference? An isometry also preserves angles. Don't change the question so that it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Compute the tangent in the “swapped system”; the normal is easy to write; swap back.

Comment: @PontiusPilateVII At the end, of course.

Comment: @PontiusPilateVII I added the computation.

Comment: okay, I'm un-familiar with the method, but it's certainly helped, thank you!